# Removing specific links from html?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, rss

I have links being generated by an RSS feed that lead to nowhere for some reason. They aren't important so I figured maybe I could remove the links.

Is there any way to completely remove the 'a' tag or something? What's the best way to go about this to make it plain text?

All the links begin with 'http://output". Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
  $('a[href^="http://output"]').remove();
```

This removes all `<a>` tag with the attribute href that starts with `http://output`

If you need to replace it with normal text you could do

```
$('a[href^="http://output"]').each(function(){
   var txt = $(this).text();
   var span = $('<span/>', { text : txt});
   $(this).replaceWith(span);
});
```

Comment: This is assuming the user has Prototype

Comment: @ElGuapo this is jQuery (as stated in the OP tag)